# Как запустить сервлет до запуска главной страницы?

Tags: java, веб-программирование, jsp, servlet, tomcat

Есть такой вопрос: как запустить сервлет до запуска главной страницы?

У меня есть страница `index.html`, и перед тем как она запустилась мне нужно, чтобы сервлет выполнялся и вносил данные на эту страницу.

Подскажите мне как это можно реализовать.

Answer (score 0):

Надо переименовать `index.html` в `index.jsp`, а сервлет маппиниг определить как `"/"`.

Данные можно ложить в request scope. После чего диспатчером перенаправлить на `index.jsp`.

Вы можете использовать JSP тэги, и/или EL выражения для отображения данных.

Comment: Есть вот такой код в **сервлете**:
req.setAttribute("buyUsd", arrayUsd.get(0));
req.setAttribute("saleUsd", arrayUsd.get(1));
req.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp").forward(req, resp);

В **index.jsp** :
<p>Buy USD: <%= request.getAttribute("buyUsd")%> </p>
<p>Buy EUR: <%= request.getAttribute("buyEur")%> </p>

Но при запуске страницы там null, если сделать кнопку с вызовом данного сервлета, то все норм, а вот при начальном запуске страницы не отрабатывает, даже с аннотацией @WebServlet("/")

Comment: @ivani, с маппингом "/", сервлет будет вызван по адресу "http://localhost:8080". Попробуйте "/*".

Comment: в данном случае также не работает, страница очень долго грузится и не отрабатывает, так как цикл отрабатывает, там идет же forward на нее же

Comment: @ivani я немного не точно ответил. Если Вы упаковываете Ваше приложение в war-файл и кладете его в папку  webapps (tomcat), то при маппинге "/", доступ к странице будет следующим "localhost:8080/RootDirectory".

Comment: @ivani смаппите Ваш сервлет, допустим, "/home". В адресной строке введите "localhost:8080/RootDirectory/home". Используйте <jsp-file> вместо <servlet-class> в теге <servlet>.

Comment: в данном случае я хочу, чтобы при открытии localhost:8080 сразу же отработал сервлет, и вывел данные на страницу, сейчас вот так (http://prntscr.com/jnhrhd). Но я потестил, сделал кнопку на странице <form>, которая вызывает данный сервлет, тогда все хорошо (http://prntscr.com/jnhrw6)

Comment: @ivani Сначала запустите сервлет, и обращайтесь к нему черех контекст а потом уже будете думать как его прилеписть к хосту.